# Proofreading exercise in upcoming interview

Tags: proofreading, ethics

I need your advice.

I'm applying for a marketing assistant role and the first round of interviews requires a proofreading exercise.

I have been given a PDF where I have to highlight problems. (The PDF's text is non-editable.)

The problem is that I can't spell, let alone correct grammar. Like, I really can't!

Do you think it's fine if I export the PDF and correct its spelling/grammar using Grammarly?

I know my post might sound silly, but please don't judge me. I'm a creative individual who has good attention to detail for business, but sadly spelling, grammar, etc is a huge weakness of mine.

Comment: I'm unsure whether we can really answer this. The only people who'll know for sure whether it's okay for you to use Grammarly are the people conducting the interview.

Comment: If sadly spelling, grammar, etc is a huge weakness why are you applying for a post that will almost certainly require you to use all three on a daily basis? Why not apply for something that suits your talents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unethical if you present the results of the Grammarly algorithm as your own work.

They want to assess your ability and knowledge on a skill that is presumably important to the role. If the author used Grammarly then your role would not be needed.

Certainly this is only one task of many required tasks. So don't sweat it. If it is an important and fundamental part of the position, then why would you want that job.  Besides, it would be grounds for termination when they learned you cheated on the interview.

If you don't know, you don't know. It is fine. It is the employer's decision to hire the best candidate based on a total set of skills they need.  If you have many of the other requirements, they want, you might get the job.  If you can't do that function, you'll hate the job.  Getting it by cheating will be a pyrrhic victory at best.

Comment: EDL, your comment has highlighted  my exact emotions. Thank you my friend for sharing your honest and thoughtful reply. It means a lot.

Comment: It's not cheating - it's using available resources to help you overcome an area of difficulty and think 'outside the box' - employers should not knowingly discriminate against people who are differently enabled. It's useful to know the rules, though, but you could easily list strategies you use to ensure that errors in written English are minimised and spotted. Take a look at https://www.future-perfect.co.uk/grammar-tips/ and https://www.ciep.uk/resources/test-yourself/

Comment: @LeonConrad, that kind of a weak troll. That employers are cleverly looking for someone bright enough to use a tool rather than assess an applicant's skill is obtuse at best.  I am sure you can do better, if you put your mind to it.

Comment: Feel free to edit if you feel it needs improving/changing.

Comment: @LeonConrad, comments can only be edited by the author for five minutes after submission.